# Python class attribute 'is not defined' when referenced by another class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, subclass, instantiation

Using the following, I am able to successfully create a parser and add my arguments to `self._parser` through the `__init()__` method.

```
class Parser:
    _parser_params = {
        'description': 'Generate a version number from the version configuration file.',
        'allow_abbrev': False
    }
    _parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(**_parser_params)
```

Now I wish to split the arguments into groups so I have updated my module, adding some classes to represent the argument groups (in reality there are several subclasses of the `ArgumentGroup` class), and updating the `Parser` class.

```
class ArgumentGroup:
    _title = None
    _description = None

    def __init__(self, parser) -> ArgumentParser:
        parser.add_argument_group(*self._get_args())

    def _get_args(self) -> list:
        return [self._title, self._description]


class ArgumentGroup_BranchType(ArgumentGroup):
    _title = 'branch type arguments'


class Parser:
    _parser_params = {
        'description': 'Generate a version number from the version configuration file.',
        'allow_abbrev': False
    }
    _parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(**_parser_params)
    _argument_groups = [cls(_parser) for cls in ArgumentGroup.__subclasses__()]
```

However, I'm now seeing an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "version2/args.py", line 62, in <listcomp>
    _argument_groups = [cls(_parser) for cls in ArgumentGroup.__subclasses__()]
NameError: name '_parser' is not defined
```

What I don't understand is why `_parser_params` do exist when they are referred by another class attribute, but `_parser` seemingly does not exist in the same scenario? How can I refactor my code to add the parser groups as required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from the confluence of two quirks of Python:

1. `class` statements do not create a new local scope
2. List comprehensions *do* create a new local scope.

As a result, the name `_parser` is in a local scope whose closest enclosing scope is the global scope, so it cannot refer to the about-to-be class attribute.

A simple workaround would be to replace the list comprehension with a regular `for` loop.

```
_argument_groups = []
for cls in ArgumentGroup.__subclasses()__:
    _argument_groups.append(cls(_parser))
```

(A better solution would probably be to stop using class attributes where instance attributes make more sense.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I can confirm that your workaround has done the job. I'm not a Python expert though, so could you possibly expand on why instance attributes would make more sense then class attributes? Is it simply because that's the way to get it working in this case, or is there some overriding principle that I'm missing?

Comment: The fact that you access them via `self` suggests they are specific to a particular *instance* of `Parser`, rather than *all* possible instances of `Parser`. (The line is blurred a bit if you don't intend to create more than one instance, but the distinction is still there.)

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip. I'm sure my code will change anyway, because as noted I'm not a Python expert, so I'll keep this thread in mind at that time.